# Getting Unicode in copy and paste within emacs

Tags: unicode, copy-paste, emacs24

I try to do copy and paste in emacs on a Mac but in the most recent version of gnu emacs (24.3.1) this does not work. Instead of Tesnière I get ﻿Tesni\350re. Is there some switch?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

C-x RET x

then select utf-8 (which is probably what you want)

C-x RET x (translated from C-x  x) runs the command
set-selection-coding-system (found in global-map), which is an
interactive compiled Lisp function in `mule.el'.

It is bound to C-x RET x,   
 .

(set-selection-coding-system CODING-SYSTEM)

Make CODING-SYSTEM used for communicating with other X clients.
When sending or receiving text via cut_buffer, selection, and clipboard,
the text is encoded or decoded by CODING-SYSTEM.